# I'm completely baffled by this, because the else if statement seems to break the program?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, console.log

So I'm writing a piece of coed for my brother and I think it is really odd because the first console log outputs undefined, which is expected, and the second one outputs '1229/4096', which is what I would expect too, but the third one outputs undefined which I think is pretty odd. If anyone can tell me why or help me fix it, or even ask for any other bits of code, I would love some help!

```
        let catchRate = document.getElementById('catchRate').value;
        let x;
        console.log(x)

        if (catchRate >= 0 && catchRate <= 30) {
            let x = (1229/4096);
            console.log(x);
        } else if (catchRate >= 31 && catchRate <= 150) {
            let x = (2048/4096);
        } else if (catchRate < 150) {
            let x = (2867/4096);
        }

        console.log(x)
```

Comment: You only need to declare `x` with `let` **once**, outside the `if` stuff.

Comment: if 'catchRate' not less than 150 and or not a value comparable to 150 then will still be undefined

Comment: Also, `input.value` is always a string. Keep in mind that you're getting `"30"`, not `30`.

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring a new variable `x` in your if/else block by using `let`. So therefore you're NOT reassigning the value of your original `x`, declared on line 2. If you want to re-assign the value of that SAME `x` variable, don't use `let x = 123` in your if/else block. Just use `x = 123`.

Closed. This question is not reproducible or was caused by typos. It is not currently accepting answers.
This question was caused by a typo or a problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

Closed 1 min ago by Pointy, A.J. Uppal, Mark Baijens.

(Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege)

Edit question
So I'm writing a piece of coed for my brother and I think it is really odd because the first console log outputs undefined, which is expected, and the second one outputs '1229/4096', which is what I would expect too, but the third one outputs undefined which I think is pretty odd. If anyone can tell me why or help me fix it, or even ask for any other bits of code, I would love some help!

```
let catchRate = document.getElementById('catchRate').value;
let x;
console.log(x)

if (catchRate >= 0 && catchRate <= 30) {
    x = (1229/4096);
    console.log(x);
} else if (catchRate >= 31 && catchRate <= 150) {
    x = (2048/4096);
} else if (catchRate < 150) {
    x = (2867/4096);
}

console.log(x)
```